# Oracle VIEW - More than 4000 bytes in Column

Tags: sql, oracle

Iam using this part of an SQL Satement to fetch Information from an N:N Relationship.

The Goal is to have an view with an column like: "**STRING1,STRING2,STRING3**". This works fine but i have sometimes more than 4000 Bytes in the Column.

```
 (SELECT
     (RTRIM(XMLAGG(xmlelement(X, TABLE1.STRING||',') order by TABLE1.STRING).extract('//text()'),','))
    FROM
        STRING_HAS_TABLE1
    JOIN TABLE1 STRING_HAS_TABLE1.STRING_ID = TABLE1.ID
    WHERE
      STRING_HAS_TABLE1.USER_ID = X.ID) AS STRINGS,
```

Oracle throws "Buffer overflow". I think the problem is the columntype inside the view: VARCHAR2(4000).

**ERROR: ORA 19011 - Character string buffer to small**

Any ideas to handle this without changing the whole application logic?

Comment: what exact error code do you get?

Comment: ERROR: ORA 19011 - Character string buffer to small

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem converting implicitly between data types. You can get around it by treating it as a `CLOB` before trimming, by adding a `getClobVal()` call:

```
SELECT RTRIM(XMLAGG(xmlelement(X, TABLE1.STRING||',')
    order by TABLE1.STRING).extract('//text()').getClobVal(),',')
FROM ...
```

The [`RTRIM` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions160.htm#sthref1481) shows the types it accepts, and since `XMLTYPE` isn't listed that means it has to be doing an implicit conversion, apparently to `VARCHAR2`. (The same applies to the other `TRIM` functions).

But it does accept `CLOB`, so doing an explicit conversion to `CLOB` means `RTRIM` doesn't do an implicit conversion to a type that's too small.

Comment: Rather belatedly found what I think is probably where I learnt this trick; [this old question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13299843/266304).